# Pandas: selecting multiple groups for inset plot

Tags: python, pandas

I have a group data frame (`grouped_df`) used for plotting in the following way:

```
grouped_df[['col1','col2','col3']].sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

resulting in the expected plot, which contains a group-wise sum for all three columns. However, for some of the groups these sums are very small compared to the rest and hence not easy to display in the same bar plot (see image below).

I want to have an inset plot for these groups. Trying,

```
grouped_df[['col1','col2','col3']].sum() < "cut-off"
```

returns a boolean "list" of these groups but I cannot use any further for slicing/selection the a subset of groups of the data frame.

Of course, I could generate two lists of groups and then loop through the `grouped_df` but I do not think this is really a bright solution to the problem.

[image: Example]

For clarity and consistence I provide a sample data frame which would be grouped by `grpcol`:

```
grpcol    col1     col2     col3     comment          
A         0.0505   0.0134   0.0534   foo
B         0.0505   0.0134   0.2034   bar
A         0.0505   0.0134   0.0134   bar
C         0.0505   0.0134   0.0331   None
D         0.0505   0.0134   0.0342   foo
E         0.0505   0.0134   0.2134   baz
F         0.0505   0.0134   0.0302   baz
D         0.0302   0.0134   0.2134   foo
D         0.0204   0.0134   0.0400   foo
G         0.0505   0.0134   0.2200   foo
H         0.0505   0.0134   0.1734   None
H         0.0505   0.0134   0.0073   None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
def apply_cut_off(x1,x2,x3, CUT_OFF):

    if x1 < CUT_OFF: return False
    elif x2 < CUT_OFF: return False
    elif x3 < CUT_OFF: return False
    return True

grouped_sum = grouped_df[['col1','col2','col3']].sum()


cutoff_df = grouped_sum[ grouped_sum.apply(lambda x: apply_cut_off(x['col1'], x['col2'], x['col3'], YOUR_CUT_OFF), axis=1)]
```

This would return a data frame with the columns for which at least one element is below the cutoff and then you can do whatever you want with it.

Maybe I didn't get the requirement

Comment: This works perfectly and can also be used directly with the comparison I suggested in my question. Thank you @elelias